# Difference of files from Nth line

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to get the difference of two text files. However, the first line can always change. For this reason I was executing this from a python:

```
tail -n +2 file1
tail -n +2 file2
```

Then to compare I match the results from the outputs.

However, I would like to use `awk` or `sed` if possible.

What I have found so far is:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { A[$0]=3; next } !A[$0]' file2 file1
```

but this compares from the first line.

How can I diff from the second line?

Comment: What's your input? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AvinashRaj My input? Just text files which I have already mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `diff` together with [process substitution:](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

```
diff <(tail -n +2 file1) <(tail -n +2 file2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write something like

```
awk 'NR == FNR { A[$0]=3; next } !A[$0]&&FNR>1' file2 file1
```

- `FNR>1` The `FNR` value is reset to `1` for each file read. So `FNR>1` selects all lines from the second line onwards.

Answer (score 2):

All of the current AWK answers won't show differences between files, they will simply show if one file doesn't contains lines from the other, with no respect to order or number of occurences.

An awk way that compares line by line.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[FNR]=$0}FNR>1&&!(A[FNR]==$0)' file1 file2
```

If you want both lines to be output(similar to diff(ish))

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[FNR]=$0}
     FNR>1&&!(A[FNR]==$0){
     print "Line:",FNR"\n"ARGV[1]":"A[FNR]"\n->\n"ARGV[2]":"$0"\n"
     }' file file2
```

#### Explanation

- Sets an array with File record number(FNR) as key to the line for first file.
- Checks if line in second file is the same for the same FNR as the first file.
- If it isn't print

Second one is mostly just formatting for the output.

- It outputs FNR,first arg to awk(filename1),line from array,arrow,second arg to awk(filename2),line from file2

Answer (score 1):

In addition to nu11p01n73R solution, you can always use `<(...)` for input files:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { A[$0]=3; next } !A[$0]' <(tail -n+2 f2) <(tail -n+2 f1)
```