# Check if all lines of a file are contained in another file

Tags: linux, bash, file

I have a file: `a.txt` with a number at each line. I also have another file `b.txt` with also a number at each line.
How could I check if all the lines in file `a.txt` is included in `b.txt`?

Comment: Better add sample input/output ;)

Comment: check to line number is required also?

Comment: Practically the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376807/difference-of-files-from-nth-line/27377665#27377665

Comment: @user3442743:  that question specified using sed or awk; this is more general.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397747/check-whether-all-lines-of-file-occur-in-different-file

Answer (score 6):

You can use `comm` for that.

If `a.txt` and `b.txt` are already sorted (lexically and ascending), you just need

```
comm -23 a.txt b.txt
```

or maybe

```
comm -23 a.txt b.txt | wc -l
```

If there is no output (or if `wc -l` returns "0"), then every line in `a.txt` was in `b.txt` (`-2` suppresses output of lines that are only in `b.txt`, `-3` suppresses output of lines that are in both files).

If the files are not sorted, you can use process substitution to pass a sorted output of each file to `comm`:

```
comm -23 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
```

The process substitution `<(COMMAND)` puts the output of `COMMAND` into a FIFO or a file in /dev/fd (depending on what is supported on the system). On the commandline `<(COMMAND)` is then substituted with the name of this file as part of the command line expansion.

This does really check lines, so if a number exists twice in `a.txt` but only once in `b.txt` this will output the duplicate line from `a.txt`. If you do not care about duplicates, use `sort -u FILE` instead of `sort FILE` (or `sort FILE | uniq` in case your `sort` has no switch for unique sorting)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `diff` command to compare two files

**Example usage**

```
$ seq 1 5 > a.txt
$ seq 1 5 > b.txt
$ diff a.txt b.txt
$
$ seq 1 6 > b.txt
$ diff a.txt b.txt
5a6
> 6
```

**EDIT**

You can also try something like

```
$ seq 1 5 > a.txt
$ seq 1 5 > b.txt
$ diff a.txt b.txt > /dev/null  && echo files are same || echo files are not same
files are same
$ seq 1 6 > b.txt
$ diff a.txt b.txt > /dev/null  && echo files are same || echo files are not same
files are not same
```

Comment: But for that, the order of the numbers in both files has to be the same, right?

Comment: @mrtubis Yeah it needs to be. as it comapares lines with corresponding lines of two files. You can do a sort on the two files to be safe on that

Comment: @nu11p01n73R:Yes that works for small files. But it the file has 2K lines how can I understand from the diff that it is a subset?

Comment: @Jim if the two files are same, then the diff does not give any output. where as if there is some diffirence, its shown

Comment: @Jim I have edited my answer to `echo` if there is some difference or not. Hope it helps you

Comment: The edit doesn't work since a.txt IS contained in b.txt yet they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{arr[$0]++;next}
    {print ($0 in arr) ? $0 " in both files" : $0 " *not* in both files"}
' b.txt a.txt
```

---

With [diff](/questions/tagged/diff) :

```
 $ diff -a b.txt a.txt
2c2
< 3
---
> 2
6d5
< 7
```

Answer (score 1):

if the numbers are unique (without repetitions in each file), you can concatenate them, and pipe to sort and then uniq and check how many lines you have.

for example :

```
>> cat a.txt
1
2
8
5
>> cat b.txt
1
2
5
3
8
>> cat a.txt b.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l
5
```

since the answer is the same as the number of lines in `b.txt`, the answer is yes!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{b[$0];next}
            {if($0 in b){print $0" is present in b.txt"}
             else{print $0" is not present in b.txt"}
            }' b.txt a.txt
```

Comment: If there are multiple of the same number this may give misleading results.

Answer (score 0):

A Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Compare;
#read file a.txt
open (my $fh, "<", "a.txt") or die $!;
while (<$fh>){
    push @atxt = $_;
}
close($fh); 
#read file b.txt
open (my $fh2, "<", "b.txt") or die $!;
while (<$fh2>){
    push @btxt = $_;
} 
close($fh2);

my $lc = List::Compare->new(\@atxt, \@btxt);

print $lc->get_intersection;
print $lc->get_union;
print $lc->get_unique;
print $lc->get_complement;
```

There are many more options, check out the documentation: http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/List-Compare-0.39/lib/List/Compare.pm

Answer (score 0):

A file containing another file would imply the whole content of a.txt being present within b.txt in the same order, including possible repetitions, whereas your final question:

> How could I check if all the lines in file a.txt is included in b.txt?

implies that the order and repetitions are irrelevant. As a simple example:

```
a.txt:

5
7
3

b.txt:

9
5
3
7
```

satisfies your quoted question, but not the one in the title.

Solving the quoted problem is significantly easier given that the container file is not huge (otherwise you'll run into memory problems with a straight-forward approach like the one I'll demonstrate below). A simple solution would be to create a set of all the numbers contained in b.txt, then iterate through a.txt and return false in case an item is not found in the constructed set. If this didn't happen by the time you finish iterating the content of a.txt, then return true.

This would look as follows in pseudo-code:

```
ContentSet = {}
for each element b of b.txt
    add b into ContentSet

for each element a of a.txt
    if a is not in ContentSet then return false

return true
```

This approach has the advantage that the first iteration gets rid of the possible repetitions in the container file, hence keeping the file size and thus the search time to a minimum, as well as running the second iteration faster than a naive approach given that the set has a good hash implementation, because checking whether the hashset contains a given object is an O(1) operation.